# Correct Way to Write to IsolatedStorage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

In examples on how to use IsolatedStorage I have found two main techniques:

```
var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(appStorage.CreateFile("fileName", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Text");
    writer.Close()
}
```

And the other:

```
var appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("fileName", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, appStorage)))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Text");
    writer.Close();
}
```

My question is: Is there any real difference between these two techniques?

As well as: Is either method usually preffered by developers? Or is it just down to personal Opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are doing the same thing.

As you can see here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.createfile.aspx

`IsolatedStorageFile.CreateFile` returns an `IsolatedStorageFileStream`

Therefor use either.

If it were me however, I would use the one with the least amount of abstraction. It will make things clearer and ultimately faster.

Comment: `It will make things clearer and ultimately faster.` I beg to differ. Calling `CreateFile` clearly shows what the code is trying to do, while `new StreamWriter` forces the reader to go through the list of parameters to understand. But ultimately, it's just a matter of taste.

Comment: @KooKiz I suppose it depends on your understanding of the classes and what they are doing. To me the least amount of abstraction is clearer. However, I can understand if you aren't familiar with the libraries then create file is clearer.

Comment: @KooKiz at very least we can agree that the least amount of code that is executed then the faster it will be.

Comment: Definitely. I could try to nitpick by mentioning that the JIT compiler will probably inline the abstract method, speeding it up. Still, the abstract method will be at best as fast as the concrete one, never faster. That said, I don't think this kind of micro-optimization outweighs the gains of a more-readable code. So in the end, my answer will just be the same as yours: use whichever suits your tastes the best.

Comment: Just to be clear when you say the one with the least abstraction are you referring to the top or bottom method?

Comment: What i mean by abstraction is that the CreateFile is another level down from IsolatedStoragefileStream so it takes a fraction of a second longer to initialize and execute. So the least abstraction would be just calling the IsolatedStorageFileStream directly